# How do I select suitable rows from different relevant columns? (pandas Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Everyone.I am the beginner for Pandas. 
  My aim: select the most valuable team from the "team_list".
  the most valuable team means: most goals,least Yellow and Red Cards . 
  the "team_list" consists of "Team","Goals","Yellow Cards","Red Cards" - four columns. 
[team_list shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob4lo.png)

```
I want to solve the question like this,but it isn't python style. How can I do that?

sortGoals=euro.sort_values(by=['Goals'],ascending=False);
sortCards=sortGoals.sort_values(by=['Yellow Cards','Red Cards']);
print (sortCards.head(1));
the result :
              Team  Goals  Yellow Cards  Red Cards
5          Germany     10             4          0

the team information :
euro=DataFrame({'Team':['Croatia','Czech 
Republic','Denmark','England','France','Germany',
'Greece','Italy','Netherlands','Poland','Portugal','Republic of 
Ireland','Russia','Spain','Sweden','Ukraine'],'Goals':[4,4,4,5,3,10,5,6,2,2,6,1,5,12,5,2],'Yellow 
Cards':[9,7,4,5,6,4,9,16,5,7,12,6,6,11,7,5],'Red Cards':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]})

euro:
                Team  Goals  Yellow Cards  Red Cards
0               Croatia      4             9          0
1        Czech Republic      4             7          0
2               Denmark      4             4          0
3               England      5             5          0
4                France      3             6          0
5               Germany     10             4          0
6                Greece      5             9          1
7                 Italy      6            16          0
8           Netherlands      2             5          0
9                Poland      2             7          1
10             Portugal      6            12          0
11  Republic of Ireland      1             6          1
12               Russia      5             6          0
13                Spain     12            11          0
14               Sweden      5             7          0
15              Ukraine      2             5          0
```

Joran Beasley inspires me, thank you.

```
   euro['RedCard_rate']=euro['Red Cards']/euro['Goals'];
   euro['YellowCard_rate']=euro['Yellow Cards']/euro['Goals'];
   sort_teams=euro.sort_values(by=['YellowCard_rate','RedCard_rate']);
   print (sort_teams[['Team','Goals','Yellow Cards','Red Cards']].head(1));

  the results:
          Team  Goals  Yellow Cards  Red Cards
   5   Germany     10             4          0
```

Comment: Please make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I add my way to solve the question .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
germany = euro.loc[euro.Team == 'Germany']
```

More on pandas here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html

Comment: thank for your comment. 
In fact, I don't know who is the most valuable team, need to compare the 'Goals', 'Yellow Cards' and 'Red Cards'. how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
df[df['Team'].eq('Germany')]
      Team  Goals  Yellow Cards  Red Cards
5  Germany     10             4          0
```

Comment: I don't know who is the most valuable team, need to compare the 'Goals', 'Yellow Cards' and 'Red Cards'. how can I do that ?
 thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas

df =pandas.DataFrame({'Team':['Croatia','Czech Republic',
'Denmark','England','France','Germany', 
'Greece','Italy','Netherlands','Poland','Portugal','Republic of Ireland',
'Russia','Spain','Sweden','Ukraine'],
'Goals':[4,4,4,5,3,10,5,6,2,2,6,1,5,12,5,2],
'Yellow Cards':[9,7,4,5,6,4,9,16,5,7,12,6,6,11,7,5],
'Red Cards':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]})

scores = df['Goals'] - df['Yellow Cards'] - df['Red Cards']
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'Team': df['Team'],'score':scores})
print(df2['Team'][df2['score'].idxmax()])
```

is that what you mean?

Comment: you enlighten me, thank you. I can get the rate: df['Yellow Cards']/df['Goals'] and then sort the rate .